# Getting the average of the previous "x" amount of days into the current position of the new Pandas column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv

I need help with getting the average of the previous X amount of days into the current position of the new column.

The problem I am having is at the line of code `df['avg'] = (df['Close'].shift(0) + df['Close'].shift(1)) / 2`.

This is what I want, but of course, I want it to be dynamic. That is where I need help! I can't figure out how to do so because I am having issues with how it already seems to by looping itself when called.

I understand what it is doing and why (...I think) but can't figure out a way around it to get my desired result.

```
import pandas as pd
import os
import sys
import NasdaqTickerSymbols as nts    
class MY_PANDA_INDICATORS():
    
    def __init__(self, days, csvFile):
        self.days = days
        self.df = None
        self.csvFile = csvFile


    def GetDataFrame(self):
        modpath = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(sys.argv[0]))
        datapath = os.path.join(modpath, "CSV\\"+ self.csvFile + ".csv")
        df = pd.read_csv(datapath)
        return(df)    

    def GetEMA(self):
        df['avg'] = df['Close'].shift(0) + df['Close'].shift(1) 
        return(df)
    

myD = MY_PANDA_INDICATORS(2,nts.matches[0])
print(myD.GetEMA())
```

Here is what I am getting and also what I want, but I want to be able to change the number of days and get the average of that "x" amount I pass to it. I have tried looping but none work as intended.

```
           Date  Open  High   Low  Close  Adj Close  Volume    avg
0    2020-11-16  1.15  1.15  1.11   1.12       1.12   17100    NaN
1    2020-11-17  1.15  1.15  1.11   1.13       1.13   29900  1.125
2    2020-11-18  1.15  1.20  1.12   1.16       1.16  127700  1.145
3    2020-11-19  1.17  1.22  1.16   1.16       1.16   64500  1.160
4    2020-11-20  1.18  1.18  1.14   1.15       1.15   32600  1.155
..          ...   ...   ...   ...    ...        ...     ...    ...
246  2021-11-08  2.40  2.40  2.31   2.32       2.32   20000  2.340
247  2021-11-09  2.35  2.35  2.28   2.31       2.31   19700  2.315
248  2021-11-10  2.29  2.31  2.20   2.20       2.20   24200  2.255
249  2021-11-11  2.20  2.22  2.18   2.21       2.21   18700  2.205
250  2021-11-12  2.21  2.22  2.18   2.21       2.21    7800  2.210
```

Comment: Will you please provide a sample of your dataframe? And also, a sample of what output you want?

Comment: Your function `GetEMA` does not return anything, so your call to `print(myD.GetEMA())` probably printed `None`. Did you mean to add `return df` or something similar to the end of `GetEMA`?

Comment: What do you want `print(myD.GetEMA())` to print, exactly?

Comment: Sorry. Did some editing and also answered the question of what I am looking for.

Comment: Basically you want to specify a number X, say 80, and return the first X (80) days? or _last_ X days? or what?

Comment: So I want the first 80 "closes" and then divide that by 80 and then store that value into the current position of the new column. Sorry the code has typos, but yes this is what I am looking to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can [reindex](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) your DataFrame by the date, and then perform a [rolling](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rolling.html) mean and with the argument x number of days as a string (such as `"2D"`):

```
df['avg'] = df.set_index(["Date"]).rolling(f"{self.days}D").mean().values
```

On a smaller example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'date': pd.date_range('2021-01-01','2021-01-05'), 'close':[1,3,5,7,9]})
```

Input:

```
>>> df
        date  close
0 2021-01-01      1
1 2021-01-02      3
2 2021-01-03      5
3 2021-01-04      7
4 2021-01-05      9
```

---

```
df['avg'] = df.set_index(["date"]).rolling("2D").mean().values
```

Output:

```
>>> df
        date  close  avg
0 2021-01-01      1  1.0
1 2021-01-02      3  2.0
2 2021-01-03      5  4.0
3 2021-01-04      7  6.0
4 2021-01-05      9  8.0
```

Comment: Thank you for this. This is what I was looking for. Your help is much appreacatied. Also thanks to everyone else who chimed in. I will try to do a better job of explaining and writing it out next time I have a question.